# Issue sending email from Javascript with WP SMTP Mail

Tags: wordpress, smtp, phpmailer, wp-mail

I have successfully setup the WP SMTP Mail plugin - test emails (from the plugin setup page) come through no problem.

I'm now trying to send a simple email from Javascript from a page on the same WordPress site.  The code is:

```
<script>
function sendEmail() {
  var data = {
    'to': 'mark1345@gmail.com',
    'subject': 'Hello',
    'message': 'Hello, world!'
  };

  jQuery.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp_smtp_mail_send', data)
    .done(function(response) {
      console.log('Email sent successfully.');
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      console.log('Error sending email.');
    });
}

sendEmail();
</script>
```

It returns: Error sending email.

Can you see anything wrong with my code?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your JS code (apart from it being a wide-open spam gateway), but the error is coming from the back end, and you've not shown us the code for that.

Comment: Hi - the backend is the WP SMTP Mail plugin- what would help from there?

Comment: As far as I’m aware the smtp mail plugin just provides smtp config, and doesn’t handle requests or actually send messages – I think you have to call it from other code. Either way, the plug-in docs should cover it.